# Data-processing takes too long if pre-processing just before

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

So I've been trying to perform a cumsum operation on a data-set. I want to emphasize that I want my cumsum to happen on partitions on my data-set (eg. cumsum for feature1 over time for personA).

I know how to do it, and it works "on its own" perfectly - i'll explain that part later. Here's the piece of code doing it:

```
// it's admitted that this DF contains all data I need
// with one column/possible value, with only 1/0 in each line
// 1 <-> feature has the value
// 0 <-> feature doesn't contain the value
// this DF is the one I get after the one-hot operation
// this operation is performed to apply ML algorithms on features
// having simultaneously multiple values
df_after_onehot.createOrReplaceTempView("test_table")

// @param DataFrame containing all possibles values eg. A, B, C
def cumSumForFeatures(values: DataFrame) = {
  values
    .map(value => "CAST(sum(" + value(0) + ") OVER (PARTITION BY person ORDER BY date) as Integer) as sum_" + value(0))
    .reduce(_+ ", " +_)
}

val req = "SELECT *, " + cumSumForFeatures(possible_segments) + " FROM test_table"
// val req = "SELECT * FROM test_table"
println("executing: " + req)

val data_after_cumsum = sqLContext.sql(req).orderBy("person", "date")
data_after_cumsum.show(10, false)
```

The problem happens when I try to perform the same operation with some pre-processing before (like the one-hot operation, or adding computed features before). I tried with a very small dataset and it doesn't work.

Here is the printed stack trace (the part that should interess you at least):

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded

[Executor task launch worker-3] ERROR util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-3,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

So it seems it's related to a GC issue/JVM heap size? I just don't understand how it's related to my pre-processing?

- I tried unpersist operation on not-used-anymore DFs.
- I tried modifying the options on my machine (eg. -Xmx2048m).
- The issue is the same once I deploy on AWS.

Extract of my pom.xml (for versions of Java, Spark, Scala):

```
<spark.version>2.1.0</spark.version>
<scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

Would you know how I could fix my issue?
Thanks

Comment: @som-snytt I updated the question providing Scala, jdk and Spark versions

Comment: There are many ways a Spark job can fail with a OOM:
A common pattern is collecting too much data on the driver or having too much data on a single worker after a group by where one of the key is over-represented.
It is hard to help you without more details about your transformation. As a starting point, you should look at the Spark GUI and check if the amount of data is evenly distributed among executors or not.

Comment: @FurryMachine thanks! I have been looking at that, but this also happens when I launch my job locally. It happens when I launch my job with pre-processing (including simple features computations + one-hot) and it does not happen if I launch it on its own (I pre-process, I store the data on my drive, then launch another JVM instance to perform the cum-sum).

The transformation I am trying to perform is a cum-sum operation (cumulative sum over time for each feature for each person, it should be done in O(n)).

Comment: Ouch, things like this can happen with Spark, and there is not much to do to  find the reason why. I would guess that there is some kind of unfortunate optimization happening when you chain the operations.  If checkpointing your intermediary result works I would say "go for it". Sometimes, just adding a persist() our sometimes just a show(), might also alter the optimizer's behavior. This can get really frustrating sometimes. This is why I always favor simple steps and store the intermediary results, so I can look at, debug, and fix each part separately. But it doesn't always make much sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, I think that we could have two reasons for that:

- JVM's heap overflow because of kept-in-memory-but-no-longer-used DataFrames
- the cum-sum request could be too big to be processed with the few amount of RAM left
- show/print operations increase the number of steps necessary for the job, and may interfer with Spark's inner optimizations

Considering that, I decided to "unpersist" no-longer-used DataFrames. That did not seem to change much.

Then, I decided to remove all unecessary show/print operations. That improved the number of step very much.

I changed my code to be more functionnal, but I kept 3 separate values to help debugging. That did not change much, but my code is cleaner.

Finally, here is the thing that helped me deal with the problem. Instead of making my request go through the dataset in one pass, I partitionned the list of features into slices:

```
def listOfSlices[T](list: List[T], sizeOfSlices: Int): List[List[T]] =
    (for (i <- 0 until list.length by sizeOfSlices) yield list.slice(i, i+sizeOfSlices)).toList
```

I perform the request for each slice of, with a map operation. Then I join together them to have my final DataFrame. That way, I kind of distribute the computation, and it seems that this way is more efficient.

```
val possible_features_slices = listOfSlices[String](possible_features, 5)

val df_cum_sum = possible_features_slices
  .map(possible_features_slice =>
    dfWithCumSum(sqLContext, my_df, possible_segments_slice, "feature", "time")) // operation described in the original post
  .foldLeft[DataFrame](null)((a, b) => if (a == null) b else if (b == null) a else a.join(b, Seq("person", "list_features", "time")))
```

I just really want to emphasize that I still not **understand** the reason behind my problem, and I still expect an answer at this level.